# Formatting code inconsistency

Tags: text, formatting, format, markdown, edit

public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }

```cs
public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
```

My question is: why does the second one work while the first one doesn't? I used the header syntax

< !-- language: c# -->

for both (note: I purposely left a space between < and ! or otherwise it won't show up; but there's no space in the original code). This is strange. Thanks for the help.

Btw I got the code from
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code needs to be indented by 4 characters, you only inserted 2 before the first example.

```cs
public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
```

```cs
public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
```